# get price from string

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers

I am trying to get a price and the plus or minus from a string using jquery. 
I'm pretty sure regex is the way to go, but I just can't seen to get it right.

**input:**
Bla bla bla bla (- € 0.25)

**should output:**
direction = -
amount = 0.25

What regexes should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript (there are no jQuery regexes), use

```
var results = input.match(/\(([+-])\s*€\s*(\d+\.\d{2})\)/);
```

For your input, the result of the [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) is:

```
results[0]: "(- € 0.25)"
results[1]: "-"
results[2]: "0.25"
results.index: 16
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"[^€]*€[ ]*\([.[:digit:]]*\).*" -> "\1"
```

This is POSIX. You can use it so:

```
sed "s|[^€]*.[ ]*\([.[:digit:]]*\).*|\1|"
```

Comment: The OP asked for jQuery (javascript). Also, your regex does not seem to match the "direction" (+ or -)

Comment: I saw. POSIX is common for all libraries, for almost all languages. Even if he does not use sed, he can convert it directly to a programming language

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that :

```
/^(.+) \((\- ){0,1}€ ([0-9\.]+)\)$/
```